# Access TextBlock Text inside a DataTemplate UWP

Tags: c#, listview, binding, uwp

I searched all over the internet on this question, but I can't made progress in my UWP application.

I have a `ListView` with a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvEszTmplt" Margin="50,61,0,0" ItemClick="lvEszTmplt_ItemClick_1" SelectionChanged="lvEszTmplt_SelectionChanged_1"   >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,8" x:Name="spItem" >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbAzonosito" > 
                                <Run Text="Azonosító: " Foreground="DarkGray"/> 
                                <Run Text="{Binding Azonosito}" 
                                     Foreground="DarkGray"
                                     />

                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbMegnevezes" > 
                                <Run Text="Megnevezés: " Foreground="DarkGray"/> 
                                <Run Text="{Binding Megnevezes}"
                                     Foreground="DarkGray"/>

                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbSerial" > 
                                <Run Text="Serial: " Foreground="DarkGray"/> 
                                <Run Text="{Binding Serial}"
                                     Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbSorszam"   > 
                                <Run Text="Sorszám: " Foreground="DarkGray"/> 
                                <Run Text="{Binding Sorszam}"
                                     Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                    </TextBlock>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

In the `ListView`, the "Azonosito" is an ID column. 
When I click on a `Item`, it should go to another `Frame` and take the ID from the `ListView`, and load the Deatails View with the data from the ID.

How can I do this?

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ItemClickEventArgs.ClickedItem` property of the `ItemClick` event to read the clicked item:

```
private void lvEszTmplt_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (ItemModel)e.ClickedItem;
    var id = item.Azonosito;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. What is `ItemModel`?

Comment: Your `ListView` should be bound to a collection of objects, where each object is a model for an item as defined in `DataTemplate`. `ItemModel` is a made up class name of objects that are bound to the list view and you should replace it in your application.

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

@Krzysztof Bracha have a good answer.But I see you forget add the IsItemClickEnabled property.

You can use `IsItemClickEnabled=true` to enabled ItemClick.

And you should bind the sources to ListView.

You also can use x:bind to binding the data.

If your sources' type is ObservableCollection that you can use the code as @Krzysztof Bracha.

If you need get the control in ListView that you can use `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(DependencyObject reference, int childIndex);` to get it.

See:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth